# Error message while trying to deploy my contract

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, web3js, hardhat

I'm currently learning solidity and I got to the stage where I deploy my contract on my terminal. I get this error message "Error HH100: Network rinkeby doesn't exist" .

Here's my hardhat.configure.js code

```
require('dotenv').config();

require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

/**
* @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
*/
module.exports = {
   solidity: "0.7.3",
   defaultNetwork: "rinkeby",
   networks: {
      hardhat: {},
      rinkeby: {
         url: API_URL,
         accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
      }
   },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

correct configuration would be

```
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "rinkeby",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
    },
    rinkeby: {
      url: "https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/123abc123abc123abc123abc123abcde",
      accounts: [privateKey1, privateKey2, ...]
    }
  }
```